# Pin secondary tile Issue windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, back-stack, secondary-live-tile

I am successfully able to pin a specific page from app to a secondary tile. But after clicking on tile only that page opens. backstack is not preserved. How can we manage to have all navigations that we had before pin operation

I have used [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868249.aspx) for Pin operation.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code of your creating tiles and how you handle launching from tile? It will make your question more clear

Comment: have provided link to code..its the same i did.